# Show specific section of HTML code based on radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons that will determine what HTML will be shown. When either is selected, it should show it's HTML and hide the other. How do I do this? Do I create the code and have it invisible, or do I add the code when a radio button is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the result you're after, you should show your code so that answers can address your specific issue.

There is only a need for one function, it can hide and show elements based on various attributes but the best is likely *class*. It can also work regardless of how many buttons and elements to show or hide that you have.

The actual method you use depends on the age of browsers you want to support, but a simple implementation is:

```js
// Function to show or hide div based on which radio is selected
function showDiv() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name=divToggle]'), function(button){
    document.getElementById(button.dataset.divid).className = button.checked? '' : 'hidden';
  })
}

// Attach click listeners onload
window.onload = function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name=divToggle]'), function(button) {
    button.onclick = showDiv;
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="divToggle" data-divid="div0">Show only div 0<br>
<input type="radio" name="divToggle" data-divid="div1">Show only div 1<br>
<div id="div0">div 0</div>
<div id="div1">div 1</div>
```

Comment: Certainly the most modular solution

Answer (score 2):

You can add code and set it to `display:none` before button is selected. Then you create two functions which always show one element and hide other.

```js
function changeContent1() {
  document.getElementById("show1").classList.remove("hide");
  document.getElementById("show2").classList.add("hide");
}

function changeContent2() {
  document.getElementById("show1").classList.add("hide");
  document.getElementById("show2").classList.remove("hide");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onclick="changeContent1();" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onclick="changeContent2();" value="2" />
<div id="show1" class="hide">
  <p>First div</p>
</div>
<div id="show2" class="hide">
  <p>Second div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others answered here is another one that should work:

```
<div id="one" hidden>fdsfdss</div>
<div id="two" hidden>content~~~</div>

  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="maleid" onclick="handleOne()">
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="genderid" onclick="handleTwo()">

const genderElement = document.getElementById("genderid");

function handleOne() {
  const divOne = document.getElementById("one");
  if (divOne.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
    divOne.removeAttribute('hidden');
  } else {
    divOne.setAttribute('hidden');
  }
}
function handleTwo() {
  const divTwo = document.getElementById("two");
  if (divTwo.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
    divTwo.removeAttribute('hidden');
  } else {
    divTwo.setAttribute('hidden');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind radio buttons to your application with the ng-model directive.

Radio buttons with the same ng-model can have different values, but only the selected one will be used.

```
<form>
  Pick a topic:
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="dogs">Dogs
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="tuts">Tutorials
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="cars">Cars
</form>

<div ng-switch="myVar">
  <div ng-switch-when="dogs">
     <h1>Dogs</h1>
     <p>Welcome to a world of dogs.</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="tuts">
     <h1>Tutorials</h1>
     <p>Learn from examples.</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="cars">
     <h1>Cars</h1>
     <p>Read about cars.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP is using angular.js?

Comment: I tried running this in a file, and nothing happens. All the divs show up on a page at once, and the radio buttons don't act independently of each other. Do I need a framework or something?

Comment: @SethPainter : Try https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_form_radio

Comment: @SethPainter This work only if you use Angular.js framework

Comment: @SethPainter : ohh u want plain js script witout angular

Answer (score 0):

with JQuery

```js
$("#input1").click(function(){
  $("#par1").css("display", "block");
  $("#par2").css("display", "none");
 });
 $("#input2").click(function(){
  $("#par2").css("display", "block");
  $("#par1").css("display", "none");
 });
```

where input1 and input2 id for radio button 1 and 2 and same with par1 and par2 - for paragraphs

Comment: There is no jQuery tag and the OP hasn't mentioned it.

Comment: jquery is easy to add and easier to use in this scenario